# EF Core 2: Database first with many-to-many (linking table)

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-database-first, ef-core-2.0

I have many-to-many relationship between Projects and Models in my database

[image: Relationship diagram]

I am using this command to generate the .cs models:

> Scaffold-DbContext "my connection string here" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir EFModels -Force -Context EFEntities -Tables Projects, Projects_Models, Models

In EF6, this would create `Project.Models` and `Model.Projects` properties, without mapping the Projects_Models table into its own class.

But in this case (EF Core), it created a `ProjectsModel` class, and `Project.ProjectsModels` and `Model.ProjectsModels` properties instead.

How can you make it behave like it was in EF6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not currently possible to do this in EF Core as that feature has not yet been added. From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#many-to-many):

> Many-to-many relationships without an entity class to represent the join table are not yet supported. However, you can represent a many-to-many relationship by including an entity class for the join table and mapping two separate one-to-many relationships.